# android populate a listview by different arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist

I want to populate a listview dinamically,i have an activity with lisview and I want to load in that list different ArrayLists,i mean i have a list for contacts and I want to load it in listview,then a list for countries and I want to load it in listview,and I don't want to make an activity for every ArrayList,any ideea how to load in lisview by arraylist?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ListActivity` and populate the list by creating an `ArrayAdapter` with the desired list:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private static final List<String> 
    contacts = new ArrayList<String>(),
    countries = new ArrayList<String>();

private void displayContacts() {
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contacts));
}

private void displayCountries() {
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, countries));
}

}
```

Comment: sorry, i understand what you said,i will try,tank's

Answer (score 0):

You could reuse the same ListView, but just loading the data in without any transition will be very jarring for the user. Instead, you can create a new instance of your activity each time you need it (via an Intent) and pass in the data there to display. That way you can reuse most of your code.